# MudBlazor DropZone "onChange" event

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I need to save the log of the movements between Dropzones in a database.

I have the connection made with swagger so i only need to call a function that write the change (for example, i move 'Francisco' item to 'Super ocupados' drop zone):

[image]

And in that change i want to call this async method (Imagine that it writes the change in the bd):

[image]

There is some way to detect this change and call a function, something like an 'OnDroppedItem' or an 'OnChange'?

I think that there isn't an easy way to do this so... how i made this log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the EventCallback `ItemDropped`.
You can information with example code [here](https://mudblazor.com/components/dropzone#basic-usage).

The code you are looking for from the documentation:

```
<MudDropContainer T="DropItem" Items="_items" ItemsSelector="@((item,dropzone) => item.Identifier == dropzone)" ItemDropped="ItemUpdated" Class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-grow-1">
....
</MudDropContainer>

@code
{
    private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<DropItem> dropItem)
    {
        dropItem.Item.Identifier = dropItem.DropzoneIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, i dont saw that when i copy and paste the code :P as i say in my answer

Comment: @ZeroCodeException I added my answer at the same moment as you. Glad I could help :DD

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, i am so dumb that i havent realized that in the **first** example code of mudblazor page (code that i **literally copy and paste**) there was a function that make this:

[image]

Sorry for this, i think that im not going to delete the question because maybe this help someone whit the same problem in the future :/